# How to join a base table with update table with change data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (in real code there is more data columns, this is just an example with single data column)

```
create table base_t (
    id int primary key,
    val int;
);
create table update_t (
    id int primary key,
    c char (1),
    val int;
);
```

In update table, char column can be 'A' (add), 'D' (delete) or 'U' (update). In the result view I need to get rows from `update_t` when c is 'A' or 'U', when c is 'D' that row should not be present in result and all other rows should be taken from `base_t` table.

Example
contents of base_t table

```
1 10
2 20
3 30
```

contents of update_t table

```
2 'U' 21
3 'D' NULL
4 'A' 41
```

expected result

```
1 10
2 21
4 41
```

How to create such join in postgresql?

Comment: First, do not use reserved words for table and column names (e.g. *update*). Second, how are your tables related? And finally, please share some sample data, desired results and what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE()` for the `U` rows, preferring the `update_t` table over the `base_t` table. This is assuming that no `A` records in `update_t` would exist yet in `base_t`. Otherwise you could change that `COALESCE()` over to a case expression like `CASE WHEN update_t.c = 'UPDATE' then update_t.id ELSE base_t.id END as id` (and similar for `val`) column.

```
SELECT COALESCE(update_t.id, base_t.id) as id,
    COALESCE(update_t.val, base_t.val) as val
FROM base_t
    FULL OUTER JOIN update_t 
         ON base_t.id = update_t.id
WHERE 
    update_t.c <> 'D'
```

Comment: It works well after changing the last condition to "update_t.c IS NULL OR update_t.c <> 'D'"